Looking to drill into another Tableau dashboard and have that dashboard parameter filtered based on original selection
I have a Tableau workbook with 2 dashboards. Dashboard1 contains a landing page with employee separation data. Dashboard2 is a data table containing row-level data of employee separations. Dashboard 2 has a Parameter set up that filters the dashboard based on the Separation Type (retirement, resignation, etc..). I would like to have users select a metric on the Dashboard1 that will take them directly to Dashboard2 which will be filtered on that selection. Ex. User selected the sheet with the retirement metric in Dashboard1, they are then redirected to Dashboard2 and the data table is filtered on the Retirement parameter of the Separation Type parameter.
